# Error in dynamic data filtering While Upgrading. Net framework 3.5 to 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm getting the folowing error on my custom 'List' page that uses Dynamic Data Filtering.

"The DynamicControl/DynamicField needs to exist inside a data control that is bound to a data source that supports Dynamic Data."

I am upgrading. Net framework 3.5 to 4.5 and using catalyst.web.dynamicdata dll
I am using visual studio 2017

<%@ Register Assembly="Catalyst.Web.DynamicData" Namespace="Catalyst.Web.DynamicData" TagPrefix="ddasp" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/DynamicDataa/Content/GridViewPager.ascx" TagName="GridviewPager" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/DynamicDataa/Content/FilterUserControl.ascx" TagName="DynamicFilter" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<ddasp:DynamicFilterForm ID="DynamicFilterForm1" DataSourceID="GridDataSource" runat="server">

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Nombre activo</td>
                <td>
                      <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl3" runat="server" DataField="Name"
                        FilterMode="Contains" /></td>
                <td>
                    Marca</td>
                <td>
                        <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl1" runat="server" DataField="Brand"
                        FilterMode="Contains" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Modelo</td>
                <td>
                        <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl2" runat="server" DataField="Model"
                        FilterMode="Contains" /></td>
                <td>
                    Ubicacion</td>
                <td>
                        <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl4" runat="server" DataField="Location"
                        FilterMode="Contains" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Serial</td>
                <td>
                        <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl5" runat="server" DataField="Serial"
                        FilterMode="Contains" /></td>
                <td>
                    Sucursal</td>
                <td>
                       <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl6" runat="server" DataField="Branch"
                        FilterMode="Equals" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Tipo de Servicio</td>
                <td>
                        <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl7" runat="server" DataField="ServiceType"
                        FilterMode="Equals" /></td>
                <td>
                    Capacidad</td>
                <td>
                        <asp:DynamicFilterControl ID="DynamicFilterControl8" runat="server" DataField="Capacity"
                        FilterMode="Contains" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Search" CausesValidation="false">Search</asp:LinkButton><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Clear" CausesValidation="false">Clear</asp:LinkButton><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandName="Browse" CausesValidation="false">Browse</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
         </FilterTemplate>
       
        </ddasp:DynamicFilterForm>
```